# Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

My problem is that I cannot horizontally center a triangle pointer.

Well, I can center the pointer for some window sizes, but when I shrink or extend the window it places it in the wrong place again.

What am I missing?

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.container {
  width: 98%;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.container-decor {
  border: 4px solid #C2E1F5;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: times;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background: #88B7D5;
  text-align: justify;
}
.container:before {
  top: -33px;
  left: 48%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  border: solid #C2E1F5;
  border-width: 4px 0 0 4px;
  background: #88B7D5;
  content: '';
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-decor">great distance</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have your arrow centered with `left:48%`. This positions the arrow *near the center* of the container based on the arrow element's left edge.

In other words, assume you used `left:50%` (which is the correct way to go), this *doesn't* center the arrow element in the container. It actually centers the *left edge* of the element in the container.

In the image below a marker is centered on the page using `text-align:center`.

For comparison, see your arrow centered with `left:50%`.

[image]

The element is positioned center-right. This misalignment becomes more noticeable as the window gets smaller.

As a result, it is common to see centered, absolutely positioned elements use the `transform` property:

```
.triangle {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

The `transform` rule tells the triangle to shift itself back by 50% of its width. This makes it perfectly centered on the line. Now it emulates `text-align:center`.

[image]

In `translate(-50%,0)`, the first value targets the x-axis (horizontal), the other applies to the y-axis. An equivalent rule would be `transform:translateX(-50%)` (there's also `transform:translateY()`).

> As an aside, here's how to center an element both horizontally and
>   vertically using this method:
>
> ```
> .triangle {
>    position: absolute;
>    left: 50%;
>    top: 50%;
>    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
> }
> ```
>
> *Note: If you were using `right: 50%` or `bottom: 50%`, the respective `translate` values would be `50%` (not negative)*.

In this particular question, however, an issue arises because `transform:rotate(45deg)` is also in the declaration block. Adding a second `transform` means the first one is ignored (per the cascade).

So, as a solution, try this:

```
.container::before {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0) rotate(45deg);
}
```

By chaining functions together, multiple functions can be applied.

Just note that order matters. If `translate` and `rotate` were reversed, the triangle would first rotate 45 degrees and then shift -50% *along the rotated axis*, breaking the layout. So make sure that `translate` goes first. (Thanks [@Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) for pointing this out in the comments.)

Here's the full code:

```css
body {
    background: #333333;
}

.container {
    width: 98%;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container-decor {
    border: 4px solid #C2E1F5;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: times;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background: #88B7D5;
    text-align: justify;
}

.container::before {
    top: -33px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0) rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    border: solid #C2E1F5;
    border-width: 4px 0 0 4px;
    background: #88B7D5;
    content: '';
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-decor">great distance</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tt9opef6/)

Comment: Note the order of transforms in `translate(-50%,0) rotate(45deg)` is important. Using `rotate(45deg) translate(-50%,0)` would first rotate, so then the translation direction would be rotated, and the result would be wrong.

Comment: and the explanation of the importance of order is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077632/simulating-transform-origin-using-translate :p

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use the new CSS3 `calc()` function which allows you to do arithmetic to figure out the center point.

To get your center point, the calculation will have to be:

```
50% - (56px / 2)
```

So this ends up being

```
50% - 28px
```

Putting this into the `calc()` function should then figure it out within the browser and position it perfectly in the center.

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.container {
  width: 98%;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.container-decor {
  border: 4px solid #C2E1F5;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: times;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background: #88B7D5;
  text-align: justify;
}
.container:before {
  top: -33px;
  left: calc(50% - 28px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  border: solid #C2E1F5;
  border-width: 4px 0 0 4px;
  background: #88B7D5;
  content: '';
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-decor">great distance</div>
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that you need to know the width of the item you're centering. If you want something more generic and usable across a variety of contexts, I think the transform method is probably more reliable.