# Center text over images with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to add centered text on images on hover.

This is what I've  got.

[image]

I've tried moving the text up forcefully with `margin-top`, but the results on a page resize are inconsistent.

Any ideas how to center this text?

```css
.featuredText {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg" alt>
  <div class="centeredText">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#container {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;      /* establish nearest positioned ancestor for abspos */
    cursor: pointer;
}

.centeredText {
    display: none;
}

#container:hover > .centeredText {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;               /* remove from document flow */
    left: 50%;                        /* center horizontally */
    top: 50%;                         /* center vertically */
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)   /* tweak for precise centering; details:
                                       http://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249 */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg">
  <div class="centeredText">text</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqya3a3y/)

Comment: works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT/CHANGE:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNZPwg

(only on first image to the left)

Make that:

```
.featuredText {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #fa0;
}
```

and add `position: relative;`  to `header div`

`top: 50%` moves it down 50% of the container height, `transform:translateY(-50%);`moves it back up by 50% of the textblock height, which results in vertical centering. `left:50%` and `translateX(-50%)` does the horizontal centering.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use flex on the text.  It doesn't work that way.  Flex is for a parent element.

You can do this much easier by adding relative position to the parent and then centering your absolutely-positioned text.

I'll add a code example in a minute.

```css
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 0;
}
.centeredText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg" alt>
  <div class="centeredText">text</div>
</div>
```