# Vertically align absolutely positioned element with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div that is absolutely positioned.

I'm trying to vertically align it with flex:

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    ....
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p>to</p>
        <p>you</p>
        ...
```

Is this possible? How else can I vertically align `.container`? Please note, I do not wish to use the stretching method.

```
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin: auto;
```

Also the container could be of any height.

p.s. no tables please.

Comment: If you want to vertically align the div that has the class `.container` then you should display as flex to its first direct parent and use `align-items: center` (If you want to also use the flex option).

Comment: Or if you have something absolute positioned to some container that is display as relative you can set `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` to 0 and then use `margin: auto 0`;. Or are you trying to vertical align the content instead of the div that is absolute positioned (`.container`). It is not very clear on the question.

Comment: Error404 - your first method does not work, your second method is not what im asking for.

Comment: Try with `align-content` instead in the first method.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To center the `.container` element with flex, you need to make the *parent* a flex container.

The `justify-content` and `align-items` properties are declared on a flex container, but apply to child elements (flex items).

However, since `.container` is absolutely positioned, flex won't work:

> [An absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

As an alternative, you can try this:

```
html { height: 100%; }

body {
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

.container {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

For an explanation of this centering method see this post:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Comment: "since container is absolutely positioned, flex won't work" thanks for this gem of info. I'll use transform for it to work. Nice one.

Comment: how to stop the animation of transform