# Vertical centering with relative and absolute positioning in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm using `absolute` and `relative` positioning for my `.box`, but as you can see the text doesn't seem like it's `top: 100%`.

Can someone explain why this is?

Like why is the text (*some text is going here*) spilling into the child element when `top: 100%` was specified?

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.childschild {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="dog1.jpg" alt="Picture of a dog" width="250" height="250">
    <div class="childschild">
      some text is going here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">dfd</div>
  <div class="child">dfd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .. why is the text ('some text is going here' text) spilling into the child element when 100% was specified?

Because you've applied the `transform` property to the element:

```
.childschild { transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

This tells the element to shift backward 50% of its width along the x-axis and 50% of its height along the y-axis.

So first you're telling it to be `top: 100%`. Then you're telling it to backtrack 50% of its height, which puts it back over the `.child` element. You can remove the `transform` and it will work as intended.

Try this instead: `transform: translateX(-50%);` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sLb2a9nx/))

A more complete explanation with illustrations can be found here:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because in your `transform` you are applying `-50%` to Y-axis , which means will subtract that `50%` from `top:100%`, So it will be has it you stated just `top:50%` with no `transform`

Either you only apply the transform to X-axis removing the Y-axis, as stated by @Michael_B, or you can use this code below to vertically/horizontally center the text just below the box:

```
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto
```

**Note:** I changed your `img` to `background-img` (optional)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.box > div:first-of-type {
  background: url("//dummyimage.com/100x100");
  position: relative
}
.box > div:first-of-type div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  background:red
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="child">
    <div>some text is going here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">dfd</div>
  <div class="child">dfd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, this could help you..

Try using `margin-top: -10px;`, it will reduce top's space by 10px. You can also try `marign-left`,`margin-right` and `margin-bottom`.