# Centering elements in absolutely-positioned parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Unfortunately, I am unable to center the elements in the `position: absolute` parent.

Here is my code:

```css
.cont-img {
  width:400px;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:black;
}
.desc {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  color:gold;
  display:table;
}
.centered-items {
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-img">
  <div class="image">
    
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="centered-items">
      <div class="item1">
        asdasd
      </div>
      <div class="item2">
        asdasd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PS :** I also tried the flex method but unfortunately it didn't work for me because the flex makes the elements not display.

**All I need is** to make the elements under this absolute parent centered vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CSS Positioning Method

For centering with absolute positioning it helps to use `transform`, in conjunction with the `top` and `left` offset properties. You don't need `vertical-align` or table properties.

```css
.cont-img {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
}
.desc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: gold;
}
.centered-items {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);     /* 1 */
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-img">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="desc">
        <div class="centered-items">
            <div class="item1">asdasd</div>
            <div class="item2">asdasd</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. Here's an explanation of how this works: [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

---

### CSS Flexbox Method

For centering with flexbox, here's an example:

```css
.cont-img {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
}
.desc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;             /* 2 */
    align-items: center;                 /* 2 */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-img">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="desc">
        <div class="centered-items">
            <div class="item1">asdasd</div>
            <div class="item2">asdasd</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

2. Here's an explanation of how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: thanks allot those links helped allot :) 
have a good day sir !

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```css
.cont-img {
  width:400px;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:black;
  position:relative;
}
.desc {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  color:gold;
  display:table;
}
.centered-items {
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-img">
  <div class="image">
  
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="centered-items">
      <div class="item1">
        asdasd
      </div>
      <div class="item2">
        asdasd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give height to cont-img class like below

```
.cont-img {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i cant't cuz it will be height:100% , width:100%

Comment: Then use tabel effect to this class.Likewise

.cont-img {
  width:400px;
 display:table;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
}

Comment: want make it with width:100% and height:100%; and without any positions

Comment: yes you can do it with width:100% ofcourse....or just past your fiddle link here, i'll do it ..

Comment: nevermind buddy i did it :) thanks allot for ur support xD

Answer (score 1):

Add a height:400px to .cont-img class. Then you can use absolute position and css transform to centralize your content as seen in https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/ .

```
.centered-items {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Check out this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suhvalentine/nahLyu74/25/) for more.  I also added display flex css in the fiddle in case you changed your mind.

For more information on css flexbox, you could visit https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/