# Keep element always on screen with "position: sticky"

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a container with known height (height is sometimes longer then screen).

This container has a vertically and horizontally centered element (via `flex`).

I was hoping to keep this element always on the screen vertically centered in the block in the visible portion of the container.

What I tried:

- `position:sticky; top:50%` - however this only keeps it centered on the bottom half of container.
- `position:sticky; bottom:50%` - however this only keeps it centered on top half
- `position:sticky; top: 50%; bottom:50%;` - it seems `top` overrides `bottom` so this is just like my first try with `top:50%` only
- I tried setting negative values but it didn't work

Here is a demo:

```css
.container {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.center-piece {
  background-color: green;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
}
.center-piece2 {
  background-color: steelblue;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-piece">
    #1
  </div>
  <div class="center-piece2">
    #2
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to keep it perfectly centered, while "always on screen", in the visible porition of container, both top and bottom?

Here is a screencast of my application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwYaBgolNHU

The "rawr" will be the controls for the image behind it.

Comment: `position: sticky` works only in Firefox (and Safari with prefixes): http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B - this is ok I am only targeting Firefox users.

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood your question, but can you use:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50vh;
```

?

```css
.container {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.center-piece {
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%,50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-piece">#1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rounin for trying to help! It doesn't work :( Please see this new screencast which uses your method - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84j2gaQ26yw

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE: Compatibility varies across browsers..***

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky), `position: sticky` is supported on current major browsers (Not IE).

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnp43rhf/1/)

```css
.container {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.center-piece {
  background-color: green;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;                         /* 1 */
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,50%);    /* 2 */
}
.center-piece2 {
  background-color: steelblue;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10px;                      /* 3 */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-piece">#1</div>
  <div class="center-piece2">#2</div>
</div>
```

NOTES:

1. `position: sticky` kicks in when element reaches `top: 10px` of viewport
2. [How centering works with CSS positioning and transform properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)
3. `position: sticky` kicks in when element reaches `bottom: 10px` of viewport

Comment: Thanks very much @Michael_B I will test this out now!

Comment: It didn't work :( Thanks so much for your effort to give me a solution I've been strugglign with this for a couple days - here is a screencast showing it is not working using your solution - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJAiYyjJVUE

Comment: It works in the snippet and the fiddle demo on Firefox. Your screencast doesn't match the behavior in this answer. There's a conflict or something else going on.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast reply, I'm toying with it now and will keep you updated on how it goes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use postition:absolute; or position:fixed; instead of position:sticky;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).