# Center div vertically and horizontally inside another div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

If you resize the results pane to make it narrower, you will see that the image area will be resized responsively.

I am hoping to make the text always centered vertically and horizontally when such resizing happens.

I am not able to find the right css for this.

```css
.holders {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px; /*half of image width*/
}
.holder {
  float: left; /*this cannot be changed because we have a row of blocks like the example one in the bottom*/
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  /*this is not right at this moment*/
}
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%">
  <div class="holders">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="text">
        This is text that should be in the center of the block vertically and horizontally
      </div>
      <img class="img" src="http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mddc/4tx5h1tq/34/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.holders {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  /* margin-left: -150px; */
  transform: translateX(-50%);        /* see comments below */
}
.holder {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;                           /* center text vertically */
  left: 50%;                          /* center text horizontally */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   /* horizontal & vertical centering fine-tuning; 
                                         http://stackoverflow.com/a/36817384/3597276 */
}
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%">
  <div class="holders">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="text">
        This is text that should be in the center of the block vertically and horizontally
      </div>
      <img class="img" src="http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tx5h1tq/40/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [using flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/4tx5h1tq/35/)? It will do exactly what you want it to do, with minimal changes.

```
.holders {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px; /*half of image width*/

}
.holder {
  float: left; /*this cannot be changed because we have a row of blocks like the example one in the bottom*/
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.text p {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I tested your solution. It correctly positions text vertically. However, horizontally, it is not when the image area is narrowed. You can shorten the text to "This is text" and see the position of the text when the image responsively shrinks.

Comment: That's only because you have `margin-left: -150px` on `.holders`. If you take that off, [it doesn't do that anymore](https://jsfiddle.net/4tx5h1tq/37/)

Comment: This whole html structure reflects that of an actual page. I have to center the responsive image plus text. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You are able to do the same thing with less code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
  <p class="text">This is text that should be in the center of the block vertically and horizontally</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url('http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png');
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**LINK**

https://jsfiddle.net/4tx5h1tq/42/