# Image not centered with 50%

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, centering

I have an image set to `left: 50%;`. However, it's a little too far to the right, like the selector is not in the center, but on the left side.

My CSS Code:

```
#scroll-down {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: -64px;
}

#scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("img/down-arrow.png") center no-repeat;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="scroll-down">
  <div id="scroll-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's an answer and explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the image exactly placed on center, you need to put some `margin-left` with value is **minus half of your image width**.

Please try this example

```css
#scroll-down {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
}

#scroll-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100") center no-repeat;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -32px; /* value -32px comes from (width / 2 * -1) */
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-down">
    <div id="scroll-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works perfectly

Comment: you are welcome, so can make this become checked answer :-)

Comment: I will once the 5min period is over. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `transform: translate(-50%, 0)` to center it horizontally.

(removed `margin-top` you had for `scroll-down` too for illustration)

```css
#scroll-down {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
}

#scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100") center no-repeat;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-down">
  <div id="scroll-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The image width is `64px` so to make it exactly in the center, `left` value should be `50% - 32px`.

Use: [`calc()` - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

[`calc()` browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

```css
#scroll-down {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: -64px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/31306/file-25644574-png/images/arrow_down1.png") center no-repeat;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  left:-webkit-calc(50% - 32px);
  left:-moz-calc(50% - 32px);
  left:calc(50% - 32px);  
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-down">
  <div id="scroll-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just so everyone knows, [`calc()` has global support in the low 80s.](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) (~83.46%)