# How to "cancel" out left/right for absolutely positioned element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div that is positioned absolutely and I gave it a `left` position.

For desktop it is necessary to have the `left` position of 100px.

But for tablet I want to push it all the way to the right.

To achieve this I tried doing `right: 0`, but since `left: 100px` is already defined in the CSS, the `right: 0` does not push it all the way to the right as intended.

Then I tried doing `left: 0` in tablet to cancel out the effect that it has but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to cancel out the `left` position? Something like `left: none` (I know that does not work but it's the only way I am able to explain this.)

Desktop CSS:

```
.mydiv {
    positon: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Tablet CSS:

```
@media (max-width:768px){
    .mydiv {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

I could do something like `right: 400px` to get it to the position that I want but I am just curious if there is a way where I can use `right: 0` so I know for sure that it is pushed totally to the right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To reset the `left` property use

```
left: auto;
```

You can use CSS reference to get initial values of CSS properties. For example here is the reference for the `left` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/left

Answer (score 1):

When you want to shift an absolutely positioned element all the way to the other side use `100%`.

In other words, you don't need to reset `left` or use `right`. Just override `left`:

```
@media (max-width:768px){
    .mydiv {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

And for perfect positioning, you may need this:

```
@media (max-width:768px){
    .mydiv {
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

Since `left: 100%` will align the element 100% to the other side of the container *based on the element's left edge*, this may cause the element to disappear past the right edge of the container.

The `transform` rule tells the element to slide itself back exactly 100% of its own width. More details here: [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)