# position relative doesn't contain absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

For some reason image isn't contained inside positioned column. I tried using both display inline and display inline-block on img, but still won't work. Column is a flex item with position relative. Row is display: flex.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
  /*margin-right: -1rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;*/
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Column setup */

.col,
.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-10,
.col-11,
.col-12 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
}
```

Link to my full code  http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/bBbZmL

Comment: relative position does not really contain an absolute positioned element. if you want the image inside the parent, you need to position it relative and not absolute.

Comment: @GvM https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: if you want that, you need to set the height of the parent larger than your image.

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3fx405uz/

Comment: @GvM Oh, I see now. So if we don't have a container larger than the image, then we can just simply position the image relatively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `left: 0;` to `img`

```
img{
max-width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 0; /* <<< */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I wonder why we need to declare `left: 0;` and `right: 0;`

Comment: @Limpuls, by applying `position: absolute` you're just removing the element from the normal flow. You're not actually positioning it anywhere. You need to then use the CSS offset properties (`left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`) to position the element. Otherwise, the offsets default to `auto`, which leaves the element where it would otherwise be if it were in-flow ([more details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40226155/3597276)).

Comment: @Limpuls here is the best explanation about this behavior, take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968979/what-are-the-default-top-left-botton-or-right-values-when-positionabsolute-is?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Remove  position:absolute; on the img div the image will be inside a column.
it should be like this
img {max-width: 100%;display: inline-block;}

Comment: First you advise to **remove** `position: absolute;`. In the next sentence your code sample advises to **use** `position: absolute; `. Are you out of your mind?