# Absolutely positioned child element overflowing parent container

Tags: html, css, css-position

`#outer` and `#inner` must both be `position:absolute` or `fixed`.

How can I have this so that the `100%` values in `#inner` are relative to `#outer`'s width minus its padding (e.g., like a frame) and not have `#inner` overflow?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#outer {
  background: red;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}
#inner {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phcu5vah/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#outer {
  background: red;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  /* padding: 20px; */                  /* 1 */
  position: absolute;
}
#inner {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);           /* 2 */
  width: calc(100% - 20px);            /* 2 */
  top: 50%;                            /* 3 */
  left: 50%;                           /* 4 */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    /* 5 */
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. Padding on parent element will be ignored by the child, which is absolutely positioned and, therefore, removed from the document flow. Adjust the size of the child instead to achieve a similar effect.
2. Width and height of child is calculated to emulate 20px padding on the parent.
3. Vertically center element
4. Horizontally center element
5. [Make vertical and horizontal centering precise.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly less complicated code, although it uses flex-box, which isn't working in older browsers.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#outer {
  background: red;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
#inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: auto;
  flex: 0 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```