# Vertically centering a flex item works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I've written this simple code for centering my inner `div`:

```html
<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;width: 100%;height: 600px;background-color: gray;">
  <div style="background-color: white;width: 100px;height: 300px;position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

And it works fine in Chromium. but not in Firefox.

In Firefox the inner div is not centered.

Firefox:

[image]

Chromium:

[image]

I need the inner div to remain absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to note that absolutely positioned flex items *do not* participate in flex layout.

*From the spec:*

> [**4.1.  Absolutely-Positioned Flex
>   Children**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)
>
> As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex
>   container does not participate in flex layout.

In other words, flex properties, such as `align-items: center` on the flex container (like in your code) are not respected by out-of-flow flex items.

Your item appears centered in Chrome simply because that's where Chrome positions an absolutely positioned element with default offset values (i.e., `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` are all set to `auto`.) Firefox positions it somewhere else.

To vertically center your item in all browsers use the offset properties:

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

flex-item {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cutmhnp0/1/)

For more details about centering with CSS positioning properties see this post:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

For your given HTML and CSS, with the inner `<div>` element set to `position: absolute`, you are trying to vertically center a div that is taken out of the document flow.

You have a couple options for a solution.

### Option 1.

You can set the inner `<div>` to be `position: relative` and that will allow it's parent `<div>` to properly apply the behavior of `align-items: center` to the inner `<div>` (because the default `flex-direction` is `row`). Then you can absolutely position content within the inner div if needed. [codepen.io flex example](https://codepen.io/palcisto/pen/pNVWJo)

**CSS**

```
.container {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #888;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Option 2.

If you truly need the inner `<div>` to be `position: absolute`, then you can set `position: relative` on the parent `<div>` element, then set a `top` and `transform: translateY()` on the inner `<div>`. [codepen.io position:absolute example](https://codepen.io/palcisto/pen/eBrGOp)

**CSS**

```
// display: flex and align-items: center
// are not needed to vertically align
// an element that is absolutely 
// positioned

.container {
  // align-items: center;
  background-color: #888;
  // display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```