# Horizontally centering text in CSS animations

Tags: css, css-animations

The CSS seems to be horizontally centering the text by the first letter. I'd like to make it be perfectly centered on the page, without breaking the animation. I added a gradient to show the exact horizontal center of the page.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%,#ffffff 50%,#7db9e8 100%);
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.vcenter {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container h2 {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 0s;
  margin: 0;
}

.container h2:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 3s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 3s;
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 3s;
}

.container h2:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 6s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 6s;
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 6s;
}

.container h2:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 9s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 9s;
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 9s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container vcenter">
    <h2>HEY THERE THIS IS TEXT</h2>
    <h2>DIFFERENT TEXT</h2>
    <h2>THIS IS TEXT</h2>
    <h2>DIFFERENT LENGTHS OF TEXT</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276

Comment: If possible, you could remove the `display:inline-block` from `h2` tags and add `width:100%` and `margin:auto`. If the red background is required to be just around the text and not a full band, add a text container inside the `h2` tags and apply the color there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set the correct `transform` values in the `@keyframes`, also the middle div container can be removed to make it easier.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vdksf8k/)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%, #ffffff 50%, #7db9e8 100%);
}

.container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container h2:nth-child(1) {
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 0s;
}

.container h2:nth-child(2) {
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 3s;
}

.container h2:nth-child(3) {
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 6s;
}

.container h2:nth-child(4) {
  animation: rotateWord 12s linear infinite 9s;
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, 30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>HEY THERE THIS IS TEXT</h2>
  <h2>DIFFERENT TEXT</h2>
  <h2>THIS IS TEXT</h2>
  <h2>DIFFERENT LENGTHS OF TEXT</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do I have to set the translate on the animations as well, why doesn't it center if I just set h2 to "transform: translate(-50%, 0px)"?

Comment: @Tronald Because any rules set in the keyframes overrides the former ones. see this css tricks [article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) for how the centering works.