# centering a pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to set a pseudo element of a div on the original div.

The problem is that the text of the div is centered.

Here is an example:

```css
#a:after{
  content:"Text";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
  <p id="a">Text</p>
</div>
```

Why is the pseudo element not affected by the div style?

Comment: Because you've positioned it using `position: absolute`, and none of its ancestors have a non-`static` `position` property; so it's positioned relative to the view-port.

Comment: @DavidThomas ok in undestand. but i need position absolute to overlay the two texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#a:after {
  content: "Text";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
  <p id="a">Text</p>
</div>
```

Here's an explanation of the centering method: [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, without transformation:

```
#a:after {
  content: "Text";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```