# Center text in responsive hexagon grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to get the titles to be centered and work with the responsive grid of hexagons that I have. If someone could help with this, that would be great as I have been having trouble with this and already posted a question before.

Here is my code:

```css
#grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;
}

.inside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.inside * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
}

.hexagon h1,
.hex p {
  width: 100%;
}

.hexagon h1 {
  bottom: 25%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: white;
}

.hexagon h1::after {
  position: relative;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hexagon p {
  top: 70%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}


/* sizing and row indents */

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 4.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 20%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(9n+6) {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 5.5%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(7n+5) {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(5n+4) {
    margin-left: 16.666%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #grid {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="grid">

  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="#">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Author Name</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="#">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Author Name</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your elements are absolutely positioned, you can use the CSS offset properties (`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`), along with the `transform` property to center the `h1` title element.

Make these adjustments to your CSS:

```
.hexagon h1 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;                          
  left: 50%;                         
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
  margin: 0;                         
}

.hexagon p {
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

For more details about this centering / alignment method, see this post:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

```css
#grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;
}

.inside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.inside * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
}

.hexagon h1,
.hex p {
  width: 100%;
}

.hexagon h1 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}

.hexagon p {
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.hexagon h1::after {
  position: relative;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* sizing and row indents */

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 4.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 20%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(9n+6) {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 5.5%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(7n+5) {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(5n+4) {
    margin-left: 16.666%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #grid {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="grid">
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="#">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Author Name</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="#">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Author Name</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still having issues, here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mbcg9ucu/1/ so you can see where I am coming from with all the hexagons. Once it is shrunk down so that the hexagons are 2x1x2 that is when I am having the issues. Otherwise everything else looks good.

Comment: Then I would recommend wrapping both the title and text in a single container, and centering that container. https://jsfiddle.net/mbcg9ucu/3/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much again for all your help. I've been wrestling with this for awhile now.

Comment: How could I go about having different colors of text for the "title", let's say 5 different colors, for different hexagons?