# Place dollar symbol inside a text input

Tags: html, css, input, pseudo-element

I want to keep dollar symbol at beginning of text box. I am able to achieve this using the below code.

It works find in chrome and IE. The dollar symbol goes and sits next to label in firefox. How do i fix this problem? And for aligning the dollar symbol inline with text i use top 2px. Is there a way to better the css code.

```css
.input-symbol-dollar:after {
  color: #37424a !important;
  content: "$";
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
}

.input-symbol-dollar {
  position: relative;
}

.abc-input {
  border: 2px solid #c9c9c9;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #6b6f72;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  text-transform: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: #37424a !important;
  font-family: "Roboto Regular", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 42px !important;
  padding-left: 17px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

label {
  color: #37424a;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Roboto Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<label for="abcInput" class="abc-label">lable filed </label>
<span class="input-symbol-dollar">
<input  type="text" id="abcInput" tabindex="0" name="abc" class="abc-input "  placeholder="0.00"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8jdek3zt/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because the `span` is an inline element, so it's positioning isn't calculated as you are expecting it to be. The easiest solution would be to set `display: block` on the `<span class="input-symbol-dollar">`

As for positioning it in a cleaner way, you could consider making the symbol display block as well, with a height 100% of the input and set the line-height equal to the input height. I've updated your fiddle but the relevant code is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/chzk1qgm/1/

```
.input-symbol-dollar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.input-symbol-dollar:after {
    color: #37424a !important;
    content: "$";
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;

    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    line-height: 46px; // height of input + 4px for input border
}
```

Alternatively, you could just **change** the `span` to a `div`, as a div is a block level element by default. The rest of the styles would remain the same though.

Comment: But the $ symbol and text input are mis alligned. $ is little up of the text. Adjusting the top is only the fix for this?

Comment: Ah, it's misaligned because the `line-height: 42px` should actually be 46px, to account for the 4px added to the input due to the border

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's a lot of unnecessary code in your example.

Here's a simplified version that works on Chrome, Firefox and IE (not tested in Safari).

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid #c9c9c9;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-family: "Roboto Regular", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

span::before {
  content: "$";
  font-family: "Roboto Regular", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<span>
<input placeholder="0.00">
</span>
```

Here's an explanation of the vertical centering method for the pseudo-element:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Comment: Top 50% will push element 50% down and translatey -50% will pull up the element by 50% right? It should come to same position right?

Comment: `top` is pushing the element down 50% of the length of the container. `translateY` is pullling the element up 50% of its width. This makes it perfectly centered.

Comment: Here's a complete explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276

Answer (score 0):

try putting span in div.

```
<label for="abcInput" class="abc-label">lable filed </label>
<div>
    <span class="input-symbol-dollar">
        <input  type="text" id="abcInput" tabindex="0" name="abc" class="abc-input "  placeholder="0.000">
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.custom-text{
border: 2px solid #DDD;
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-text">
    <span>$</span>
    <input style="border: none;"/>
</div>
```