# Simulating transform-origin using translate

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to simulate the properties of `transform-origin` using `transform: translate` in CSS.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin), this is very possible:

> This property is applied by first translating the element by the negated value of the property, then applying the element's transform, then translating by the property value.

However, when I try, I get incorrect results. These two rectangles are clearly not the same:

```css
.origin {
  transform-origin: 100px 100px;
  transform: translate(100px, 0px) scale(2) rotate(45deg);
}

.translate {
  transform: translate(-100px, -100px) translate(100px, 0px) scale(2) rotate(45deg) translate(100px, 100px);
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box origin">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box translate">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried looking for the answer without luck for quite some time now, and in my mind it should be relatively simple, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost good but you have two errors. You need to invert the translations and you need to change the `transform-origin` of the second one.

If you check the documentation, you will see that the reference used to translate the origin is the  **top left** corner of the element and the default value of transform origin is `center`. So we need to have the same reference for both.

```css
.origin {
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  transform:  rotate(45deg) scale(2);
}
.translate {
  transform-origin:0 0; 
  transform:translate(50px, 50px) rotate(45deg) scale(2) translate(-50px, -50px);
} 
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box origin">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box translate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is from the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering):

> The transformation matrix is computed from the **transform** and
>   **transform-origin** properties as follows:
>
> 1. Start with the identity matrix.
> 2. Translate by the computed X and Y of transform-origin
> 3. **Multiply** by each of the transform functions in transform property from
>      **left to right**
> 4. Translate by **the negated** computed X and Y values of transform-origin

You need to pay attention to the wording! You may find that the MDN is contradictory with the specification BUT it's not the case simply because there is a difference between translating **the element** (like described in the MDN) and translating the **origin of the element** or the local coordinate (like described in the specification).

For example, translating the element by -50px is equivalent to translating its local coordinate (origin) by +50px.

---

You need to also pay attention to the *"Multiply from left to right"* as it may create confusion. If we refer to the same specification in the Example 3 we have:

```
div {
  height: 100px; width: 100px;
  transform: translate(80px, 80px) scale(1.5, 1.5) rotate(45deg);
}
```

> This transformation **translates the local coordinate** system by 80
>   pixels in both the X and Y directions, then applies a 150% scale, then
>   a 45° clockwise rotation about the Z axis. **The impact on the
>   rendering of the element can be intepreted as an application of these
>   transforms in reverse order**: the elements is rotated, then scaled,
>   then translated.

So multiplying from left to right doesn't mean applying from left to right which somehow explain the need of inverting the translation you applied to simulate the `transform-origin`:

Answer (score 0):

`transform-origin` can not be that easy simulated using `transform: translate`. Using `transform-origin` you change center of transformations, so rotations and all other transforms are calculated based on different point.

Take a look on below example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) with `transform-origin: 50px,50px`. Rotated element is below bottom edge of dotted square by value unable to calculated easily. You could, for sure, simulated `transform-origin` with `transform: translate` by values would need to be calculated for particular combination of values.

[image]

Comment: But then how come the MDN quote says that it is possible?

Comment: Because it is. But defining correct values for `transforms` in more complex situations is problematic.

Comment: See the other answer. Turned out to not be that problematic.