# CSS 3d transform doesn't work if perspective is set in the end of property

Tags: css, css-transforms

I found `transform` property depends on `perspective()` position

why is this happening? any other rules/limitations for `transform`?

though it feels strange to me, this not seems to be a bug as I am able to reproduce this in Chrome/FF

```css
box:nth-child(1):hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
}

box:nth-child(2):hover {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 100px) perspective(1000px);
}

box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  transition: transform .4s;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

box:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<box>
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,100px);
</box>
<box>
  transform: translate3d(0,0,100px) perspective(1000px);
</box>
```

Comment: Browser has no z-dimension information normally (why it need?). Once without telling the browser the z-position of element, how can you do 3-dimensional translation?

Comment: See: [Intro to CSS 3D transforms: Perspective](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/perspective)

Comment: @MatrixTai read about transform3d and you wil understand

Comment: @TemaniAfif , what I mean is OP must declare the perspective first, it initializes the 3d-space. This is just a inverse question.

Comment: @MatrixTai why the order really matters? I am a bit confused because when I write e.g. `transform: translate3d(0,0,100px) rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg)` order doesnt matter, but for perspective it does

Comment: @godblessstrawberry it does matter in that case also ... invert the order and you want have the same result, you have the same result only in some particular case

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow that's really surprising, I just came from 2d transforms world where (I'm not sure anymore) the order wasn't matter - my bad I expected same from 3d

Comment: @godblessstrawberry even for the 2d it matters a lot ;) you will find in my answer a link a to a previous question dealing with 2d transfrom and you will see

Comment: @godblessstrawberry, it does matter for order of `transform: translate3d(0,0,100px) rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg)`. I will make an answer cover for this too. But in theory, Temani's answer is pretty enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the `perspective` first in both cases. If you add it at the end the translation will be first made without considering the perspective.

If we refer to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) we can see how the transformation matrix is computed:

> The transformation matrix is computed from the transform and
>   transform-origin properties as follows:
>
> 1. Start with the identity matrix.
> 2. Translate by the computed X and Y of transform-origin
> 3. Multiply by each of the transform functions in transform property from
>      left to right
> 4. Translate by the negated computed X and Y values of transform-origin

As you can see in the step (3), it's from **left to right** (here is another question where you can get more information and see why order is important: [Simulating transform-origin using translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077632/simulating-transform-origin-using-translate))

It also useless to use the [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) property within the element you want to transform.

```css
box:nth-child(1):hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
}

box:nth-child(2):hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
}

box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  transition: transform .4s;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 20px;
  /*perspective: 1000px;*/
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

box:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<box>
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,100px);
</box>
<box>
  transform:  perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,100px);
</box>
```

To avoid any confusion with order you can declare the persepective within a parent element BUT you need to pay attention to the origin as it won't be the same:

```css
box:nth-child(1):hover {
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
}

box:nth-child(2):hover {
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
}
body {
  perspective:1000px;
}
box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  transition: transform .4s;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

box:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<box>
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,100px);
</box>
<box>
  transform:  perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,100px);
</box>
```

Comment: Something I don't get though. Why declaring perspective to the body as it was already declared for box element?

Comment: @PIIANTOM I moved the declaration from the box to the body

Comment: @PIIANTOM  I got your point, if you talk about the perspective declaration inside the box and not inside the transform [that I didn't notice] it useless in both cases, I removed it ... declaration perspective on an element affect only the transformed child not the element

Answer (score 1):

Though another answer already give quite clear statement how `perspective()` works. But I want to make I bit more concrete.

```css
box:nth-child(1):hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
}

box:nth-child(2):hover {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 100px) perspective(1000px);
}

box:nth-child(3):hover {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg) perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
}

box:nth-child(4):hover {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg) translate3d(0, 0, 100px) perspective(1000px);
}

box:nth-child(5):hover {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
}

box:nth-child(6):hover {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 100px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg);
}

box:nth-child(7):hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
}

box:nth-child(8):hover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, 100px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg);
}

box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  transition: transform .4s;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

box:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<box>
  1. transform: perspective(1000px) translate3d(0,0,100px);
</box>
<box>
  2. transform: translate3d(0,0,100px) perspective(1000px);
</box>
<box>
  3. transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg) perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
</box>
<box>
  4. transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg) translate3d(0, 0, 100px) perspective(1000px);
</box>
<box>
  5. transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
</box>
<box>
  6. transform: translate3d(0, 0, 100px) rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg);
</box>
<box>
  7. perspective(1000px) rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg) translate3d(0, 0, 100px);
</box>
<box>
  8. perspective(1000px) translate3d(0, 0, 100px) rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg);
</box>
```

First of all, for example 1 and 2. It is quite obvious showing how `perspective()` work for `translate3d`.

But is that mean without `perspective()`, `translate3d` is useless?

No. As I mentioned in the very first command.

> without telling the browser the z-position of element, how can you do 3-dimensional translation?

---

But, how about 2-dimensional?

Take a look on example 3 and 5. They behave completely different.

Why? Because after you do the rotation, its z-dimension is no longer your windows' z-dimension. The block move upward as 100 * cos(45) = **50px**.

And therefore, 5 and 6 work completely different, **the order between `rotate3d(1,0,0,45deg)` and `translate3d(0, 0, 100px)` does make difference.**

For 7 and 8 it is much more obvious when also the z-index becomes available for the element. It does difference.

Comment: it's a pain to hover on the element :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif, haha,  yes, as the element moved upward in those cases.