# CSS bug with transform rotateX sometimes spins far too much

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

Here you can see what I'm talking about :

```css
.layout{
 width: 600px;
 background-color: #211d1d;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 24px 9px black;
 display: inline-flex;
}

.square-container{
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 260px;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  height: 210px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 101);
  background: linear-gradient(
                  153deg,
                  rgba(51, 51, 101, 0.9) 0%,
                  rgba(0, 212, 255, 0.3) 100%
  );
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  // transition-delay: 0.1s; //helps but not radically
 }
 
 .square-container:hover>.square{
  transform: scale(1.06) perspective(10rem) rotateX(-1deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="layout">

<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square">Switch your mouse back annd forth really really fast between me</div>
</div>

<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square">and me and you'll see one of us sometimes spin crazily</div>
<div>

</div>
```

What hover should look like :

[image: normal effect]

What hover momentarily sometimes look like (the bug) :

[image: exaggerated distortion]

(sometimes the effect is exaggerated much much more than this)

What causes this and how could I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are animating the perspective. To avoid this make the perspective the same between the hover/unhover state and change only the other transform values:

```css
.layout {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #211d1d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 24px 9px black;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.square-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  height: 210px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 101);
  background: linear-gradient( 153deg, rgba(51, 51, 101, 0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transform: scale(1) perspective(10rem) rotateX(0);
}

.square-container:hover>.square {
  transform: scale(1.06) perspective(10rem) rotateX(-1deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">

  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="square">Switch your mouse back annd forth really really fast between me</div>
  </div>

  <div class="square-container">
    <div class="square">and me and you'll see one of us sometimes spin crazily</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh.... Ok nice! why does setting a perspective on the base element do nothing?

Comment: @tatsu because I am using null transformation with them. I scale with 1 (nothing) and I rotate with 0 (nothing too) so perspective will have no effect.

Comment: @tatsu also note that perspective apply to only the rotation and will never apply to scale because it comes after and the order is important. Check this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51891547/8620333