# CSS transform: translate3D not working on z-axis

Tags: javascript, css

i am making a project for fun, and it heavily relies on css transform. I tried to use the z-axis, but it appears to not work, please help!

HTML:

```
<img alt="Oops! Either the image couldn't load, or this isnt a valid link, reload and try again!" src="https://us.bravecto.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/188/2022/04/cats-bravecto-for-cats.png?w=283" id="cat">
```

JS:

```
const cat = document.getElementById('cat');

cat.animate([
   {
     transform: 'translate3D(0px, 0px, 400px)'
   },

   {
     transform: 'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)'
   }
])
```

It just wont bring the image forwards! Please help, thanks!

Comment: Please setup a m-r-e: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It likely is actually working for you... Z "axis" is how "distance" from the observer. like layers, more than up and down...  If you have not yet, please read through the web docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d

Answer (score 0):

The actual CSS first keyframe should look something like this: `transform: perspective(1000px) translate3D(0px, 0px, 400px)`.

See: [CSS 3d transform doesn't work if perspective is set in the end of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891329/css-3d-transform-doesnt-work-if-perspective-is-set-in-the-end-of-property)