# css isometric view with non iso-metric children

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, isometric

I'm using `transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);` to make an element look like it's in an isometric perspective. I'm wondering how I could revert the effect for certain children so that they share the coordination system but are normal aligned. I tried to rotate the children the same way back but it seems to work differently. Any ideas?

```css
.iso {
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;


  position: relative;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: tomato;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10rem;
  top: 15rem;
  transform: rotateX(-60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="iso">
  <h3>I'm also iso aligned</h3>

  <div class="marker">
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='30' width='27' viewBox='0 0 25 30'><path stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" fill='29434e' d='M13.6363636,0.272727273 C16.6363636,0.272727273 19.6363636,1.63636364 21.8181818,3.81818182 C24,6.27272727 25.3636364,9 25.3636364,12.2727273 C25.3636364,15.5454545 24,19.0909091 21.8181818,21.2727273 L13.6363636,29.7272727 L5.45454545,21.2727273 C3.27272727,19.0909091 1.90909091,15.8181818 1.90909091,12.2727273 C1.90909091,9 3,6.27272727 5.45454545,3.81818182 C7.63636364,1.63636364 10.6363636,0.272727273 13.6363636,0.272727273 Z'/></svg></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the `transform-origin` to make it bottom then use the opposite transformation like below. You should not only invert the values but also the order.

*Added an extra non-transformed maker to compare with*

```css
.iso {
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;


  position: relative;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: tomato;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10rem;
  top: 15rem;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(-60deg);
  transform-origin:bottom center;
}
.compare {
  position:absolute;
  left: 15rem;
  top: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="iso">
  <h3>I'm also iso aligned</h3>

  <div class="marker">
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='30' width='27' viewBox='0 0 25 30'><path stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" fill='29434e' d='M13.6363636,0.272727273 C16.6363636,0.272727273 19.6363636,1.63636364 21.8181818,3.81818182 C24,6.27272727 25.3636364,9 25.3636364,12.2727273 C25.3636364,15.5454545 24,19.0909091 21.8181818,21.2727273 L13.6363636,29.7272727 L5.45454545,21.2727273 C3.27272727,19.0909091 1.90909091,15.8181818 1.90909091,12.2727273 C1.90909091,9 3,6.27272727 5.45454545,3.81818182 C7.63636364,1.63636364 10.6363636,0.272727273 13.6363636,0.272727273 Z'/></svg></div>
</div>
<!-- to compare with -->
<svg class="compare" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='30' width='27' viewBox='0 0 25 30'><path stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" fill='29434e' d='M13.6363636,0.272727273 C16.6363636,0.272727273 19.6363636,1.63636364 21.8181818,3.81818182 C24,6.27272727 25.3636364,9 25.3636364,12.2727273 C25.3636364,15.5454545 24,19.0909091 21.8181818,21.2727273 L13.6363636,29.7272727 L5.45454545,21.2727273 C3.27272727,19.0909091 1.90909091,15.8181818 1.90909091,12.2727273 C1.90909091,9 3,6.27272727 5.45454545,3.81818182 C7.63636364,1.63636364 10.6363636,0.272727273 13.6363636,0.272727273 Z'/></svg>
```

Related questions to better understand the importance of order:

[Simulating transform-origin using translate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51077632/8620333)

[Why does order of transforms matter? SVG rotate/scale doesn't give the same result as scale/rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53671968/8620333)

Comment: Notice this example https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YzpXBQO. Here, the child object does not reset correctly after reverse rotation.  (compare the reverse rotation applied form and the no rotation on parent as well as child state)