# Understanding translate after scale in CSS transforms

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a div of 6400x3600 size. I'm using transform-origin: 50% 50%.
When I set the scale to 0.9, for the children to stay on the top left corner I need to translate to a negative value.
My reasoning was 6400 - 5760(90%) = 640 / 2 = 320... so for x it should translate -320px.. but actually what is needed is -355.556px.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/fvnq3ewj/28/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 3600px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(0.9) translate(-355.556px, -200px);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Someone have any explanation for this?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal, reproducible example. You can use the snippet tool.

Comment: @Periplo provided

Comment: A fiddle at other link is not sufficient. Please create a Stack Snippet

Comment: why not @Paulie_D? Stack let you post fiddle as long as you post code together. I'm new sorry.. just looking for some help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the translation is done after the `scale()` it will also get scaled so your `320px` need to be divided by `0.9` to get the correct value:

```
320/0.9 = 355.56
```

In other words, you need to move by `355.56px` to actually get the `320px`. It's a bit tricky but imagine your self inside another world scaled by `0.9`. The perception of the distances outside that world will not be the same inside the scaled world.

A related question to get more details about the math: [Why does order of transforms matter? rotate/scale doesn't give the same result as scale/rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53671968/8620333)

In your case:

```
scale(0.9) translate(A, B)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
|0.9 0 0|   |1 0 A|   |0.9 0  A*0.9|
|0 0.9 0| x |0 1 B| = |0  0.9 B*0.9|
|0 0   1|   |0 0 1|   |0   0    1  |
```

So

```
Xf =  0.9*(Xi + A);
Yf =  0.9*(Yi + B);
```

If you do the opposite (translate then scale) you can use `320px`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 3600px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(-320px, -180px) scale(0.9) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

The math will be:

```
|1 0 A|   |0.9 0 0|    |0.9 0  A|
|0 1 B| x |0 0.9 0|  = |0  0.9 B| 
|0 0 1|   |0 0   1|    |0   0  1|

Xf =  0.9*Xi + A;
Yf =  0.9*Yi + B;
```

Note how the translation values are not affected by the scale factor

---

If you want to go more in depth we consider the `transform-origin` to get the full formula. Here is a related question: [Simulating transform-origin using translate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51077632/8620333)

So the full matrix multiplication will become:

```
|1 0 50%|   |0.9 0 0|   |1 0 A|   |1 0 -50%|   
|0 1 50%| x |0 0.9 0| x |0 1 B| x |0 1 -50%| 
|0 0  1 |   |0 0   1|   |0 0 1|   |0 0   1 |
```

We will get:

```
Xf =  0.9*Xi + 0.9*(A - 50%) + 50%;
Yf =  0.9*Yi + 0.9*(B - 50%) + 50%;
```

We need to keep the element on the top left so for `(Xi,Yi) = (0,0)` we need to also get `(Xf,Yf) = (0,0)`

```
0 = 0.9*(A - 50%) + 50%;
A = 50%*(0.9 - 1)/0.9 
A = 50%*-0.111111
```

And `50% = 6400px/2 = 3200px`
then `A = -355.52px`

Same logic for `B` to get `-200px`

For the opposite order we will have:

```
Xf =  0.9*Xi - 0.9*50% + A + 50%;
Yf =  0.9*Yi - 0.9*50% + B + 50%;

A = (0.9 - 1)*50% = -320px
B = -180px
```