# Use Flex to center within parent, regardless of siblings

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using react and react-chartjs-2 so I think posting the markup would over complicate the question. But at a high level, the layout looks like this

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="percent">80%</div>
    <div class="pie-chart">...</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

result

[image: My Pie Chart]

The issue is that display flex is centering both children together. Is it possible to tell `.percent` to be centered within `.parent` without taking `.pie-chart` into consideration?

Comment: it means they need to be above each other, so it's a clear use case of potionning here. Use absolute position with the text and center it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change `.parent` to `position: relative` and `.percent` to `position: absolute` and center with:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Example below:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.percent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.pie-chart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="percent">80%</div>
  <div class="pie-chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: explanation for how this method works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36817384/3597276