# How to center one of the child div on the container div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

How to center only `.arrow` while keeping `.description` as it is?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="description"></div>
     <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>

.container{
    display: 'flex',
    'flex-direction': 'column'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.arrow {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36817384/3597276

Comment: Thank you @Michael_B. But when the .description content is large .arrow passes the center.

Comment: You're welcome. If you can post a full example (maybe in jsfiddle.net or codepen.io), we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks it works.

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
.arrow {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```