# Overlapping flex item has different behavior in IE11 and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

following this https://jsbin.com/limevid/1/edit?html,css,output , I notice that paragraph in IE starts from the top of the container instead in Chrome, paragraph overlap the container.

```
p {
           display: block;
           background:orange;
           width: 50px;
           line-height: 50px;
           margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

Line-height gives the height of the paragraph.
I can't change the height of container.

Why does this happen? I want for IE11 the same behavior of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **margin-top: -20px** to **P** class solves the issue for Internet Explorer.

We need to apply this style only for IE browser. so you need to write CSS like below.

It will give same result in Chrome, IE and other browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <style>
 div {
 
           display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
 
          justify-content: center;
          text-align: center;
           border: 1px solid #000;
             height: 20px;
        }

       p {
           display: block;
           background:orange;
           width: 50px;
           line-height: 50px;
           margin-left: 10px;
  
        }
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
  p {margin-top: -20px;
           display: block;
           background:orange;
           width: 50px;
           line-height: 50px;
           margin-left: 10px;
  
        }
}
 </style>
 
</head>
<body>


<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE and Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer: I already know how to fix the problem by media query, but my question was about, why IE has this behavior and if is possible find a solution that shouldn't use media query.  Thanks anyway

Comment: IE has many issues with flex. It can be one of this issues. This can be the work around for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, in many scenarios, flex renders differently in Chrome and IE.

In this case, `justify-content: center` is being interpreted differently by each browser.

If you want the content item to overlap in IE, add `margin-top: auto` to the flex item.

Or, you can use CSS positioning for full compatibility with both browsers.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
```

More details about this centering method:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)